# Do-while loop - what's wrong with the terminating condition?

Tags: c, function, loops, do-while

So I recently started learning from Steven Kochan's "Programming in C" book and I'm currently on chapter 8 - "Functions". 
I have problem with exercise 8.16:
"Modify Program 8.14 so that the user can convert any number of integers. Make
provision for the program to terminate when a zero is typed in as the value of the
number to be converted."

The code for Program 8.14 is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int convertedNumber[64];
long int numberToConvert;
int base;
int digit = 0;

void getNumberAndBase(void)
{
  printf("Number to be converted? ");
  scanf("%li", &numberToConvert);

  printf("Base? ");
  scanf("%i", &base);

  if ( base < 2 || base > 16)
  {
    printf("Bad base - must be between 2 and 16\n");
    base = 10;
  }
}

void convertNumber(void)
{
  do
  {
    convertedNumber[digit] = numberToConvert % base;
    digit++;
    numberToConvert /= base;
  }
  while ( numberToConvert != 0);
}

void displayConvertedNumber (void)
{
  const char baseDigits[16] =
    { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

  int nextDigit;

  printf ("Converted number =");

  for (--digit; digit >= 0; digit--)
  {
    nextDigit = convertedNumber[digit];
    printf("%c", baseDigits[nextDigit]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main (void)
{
  void getNumberAndBase (void), convertNumber(void),
  displayConvertedNumber (void);

  getNumberAndBase();
  convertNumber ();
  displayConvertedNumber ();

  return 0;
}
```

My idea was initially to use a do-while loop around three functions in main functions like this:

```
do
{
getNumberAndBase();
convertNumber ();
displayConvertedNumber ();
}
while ( numberToConvert != 0);
```

but apparently it doesn't work. It's the last excercise in this chapter, I managed to do the rest but not for the world can I figure out what's wrong here. 
Probably I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: define "apparently it doesn't work". What is happening? Are you getting an error, a crash, wrong results, ...?

Comment: The chapter on functions doesn't teach you to use parameters and return values? Depressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `do-while` condition is tested, it's always zero. The method `convertNumber()` has its own `do-while` that continues until numberToConvert is zero.

```
do
{
    getNumberAndBase();
    convertNumber (); // Sets numberToConvert to zero before returning
    displayConvertedNumber ();
}
while ( numberToConvert != 0);

void convertNumber(void)
{
  do {
   ...
  } while ( numberToConvert != 0);
}
```

Part of the problem is that member variables are being used to communicate return values of methods. The methods have side-effects that aren't obvious.

Consider instead returning values from the methods.

```
long int numberToConvert = 0;
do
{
    numberToConvert = getNumberAndBase();
    long int convertedNumber = convertNumber( numberToConvert ); 
    displayConvertedNumber ( convertedNumber );
}
while ( numberToConvert != 0);
```

Now the local variable numberToConvert is unaffected by the convertNumber() method, and you can determine the loop behavior from the local context.

Comment: Let's say that "the post-condition of `convertNumber` is that `numberToConvert` is zero".

Comment: @EugeneSh. -- Also true. The larger issue is the unnecessary use of a member variables to communicate function results.

Answer (score 0):

`numberToConvert` is already being used by `convertNumber()`, so let's not disturb that.

Put the whole block

```
getNumberAndBase();
convertNumber (); // Sets numberToConvert to zero before returning
displayConvertedNumber ();
```

inside a `while(1)` loop and put a check on the `numberToConvert` value in `getNumberAndBase()` function. Break out of the loop once you get the 0 value.

For sure, you can use another `do...while` loop, but somehow you need to make use of `numberToConvert` scanned value to meet the condition

> *"...Make provision for the program to terminate when a zero is typed in as the value of the number to be converted."*

That said,

- Always check for the return value of `scanf()` to ensure success.
- Don't simply use globals, they can carry hidden troubles once the program starts going large. Define local variables and pass them (or pointer to them) around as long as possible.

*Greater level of encapsulation is all we need. :)*

Answer (score 0):

This exercise is difficult because it requires the use of global variables -- which sort of works against the proper use of functions.

Anyway, here's my solution. Note that gDigit must be set to 0 each time a number is to be converted.

```
/* Exercise 7.16
   Modify Program 7.15 so that the user can convert any number of integers.
   Make provision for the program to terminate when a zero is typed in as
   the value of the number to be converted.

   notes: includes the modified version of Program 7.15 from Exercise 7.15

   the statement gDigit = 0 has been moved from the start of the program to
   the start of the convertNumber() function -- gDigit must be set to 0 each
   time a number is to be converted
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int gConvertedNumber[64];
long int gNumberToConvert;
int gBase;
int gDigit;

void getNumber (void)
{
    printf ("\nNumber to be converted (0 to exit)? ");
    scanf ("%li", &gNumberToConvert);
}

void getBase (void)
{    
    do {
        printf ("Base (between 2 and 16)? ");
        scanf ("%i", &gBase);
    }
    while ( gBase < 2 || gBase > 16 );
}

void convertNumber (void)
{
    gDigit = 0;

    do {
        gConvertedNumber[gDigit] = gNumberToConvert % gBase;
        ++gDigit;
        gNumberToConvert /= gBase;
    }
    while ( gNumberToConvert != 0 );
}

void displayConvertedNumber (void)
{
    const char baseDigits[16] =
        { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
          '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

    printf ("Converted number = ");

    for ( --gDigit; gDigit >= 0; --gDigit )
        printf ("%c", baseDigits[gConvertedNumber[gDigit]]);

    printf ("\n");
}

int main (void)
{
    void getNumber (void);
    void getBase (void);
    void convertNumber (void);
    void displayConvertedNumber (void);

    while (1) {
        getNumber ();
        if ( gNumberToConvert == 0 )
            break;
        getBase ();
        convertNumber ();
        displayConvertedNumber ();
    }

    return 0;
}
```